# Codeigniter Session ID issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have back/front end login sistems.

But using codeigniter session seems to use the same session id for both. So if i destroy the session for the backend when signing out, the session is destroyed on the front end as well. If i only unset() the userdata, the session id remains and the next admin logged in, useses the same session wich is not good.
Apparently CI autogenerate Sessions IDs. Can i do that manualy?

Any suggestions? 
Please help, i've bean checking the net for hours and i can't find a sollution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different Codeigniter installs for frontend and backend? If so, you can set different **sess_cookie_name** values in your app config.php file.

Take a look here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences

Comment: I did that,yes. The problem seems to be only if i acccess the front and back from the same browser. Apparently the session is set for the current browser and all of the windows in it, wich is very annoying. If i print_r() $this->session->all_userdata()) for the back end, it showes the current state of it but if i log in on the front end and add something in the cart for example, the array in the back changes with the data of the cart. That's just killing me.

Comment: Can you show us your frontend and backend session data array? I think you might be storing the cart/login data directly when you could use another array for front and back, let's see if we can solve this :)

Comment: this is echo  
(session_id()); c6f7a7e1f74e4bb1e3c68d65c97fe35970b43d14  and this is print_r($this->session->all_userdata());  Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1457906795 [admin_user_id] => 24 [admin_username] => 1111 )

Comment: thats from the backend

Comment: and now i've added an item in the cart from the front end and this is the change in the back :

Comment: c6f7a7e1f74e4bb1e3c68d65c97fe35970b43d14    Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1457906795 [admin_user_id] => 24 [admin_username] => 1111 [cart_contents] => Array ( [cart_total] => 222222 [total_items] => 1 [6c8349cc7260ae62e3b1396831a8398f] => Array ( [id] => 45 [name] => 33333 [qty] => 1 [price] => 222222 [rowid] => 6c8349cc7260ae62e3b1396831a8398f [subtotal] => 222222 ) ) [costumer_id] => 15 )

Comment: same session id different userdata

Comment: This is only if i use the same browser at the same time for both front and back

Comment: From what I see, the difference is that when you login to the backend you only receive **admin_user_id** and **admin_username**; when you login in frontend **cart_total** array is added to the userdata (and all is elements), this is something expected because you are using the front to store other stuff in the session (the cart). I imagine this is a problem for you because you want to have different front and back users?

Comment: Yes,they use different tables,controllers,userdata ids and names,and in the end the arrays are mixed up. But the main problem is that  both share the same session and if you destroy the session on one end, the other end is affected as well. Both use the same session id and different userdata assigned by me but the session id is assasign from codeigniter or the browser, i dont' know. I think it's browser limitataion, because i've tried to log in to facebook, the same way from one browser with different users at the same time, but it is not posible

Comment: @IvoIvanov, what **sess_cookie_name** value are you using in the front and the back? That setting is in config/config.php file.

About your Facebook comment, right: this is because you are accessing the same app in the same client (browser); otherwise you would have to login "per tab".

Comment: My sess_cookie_name is wshop_session for the entire app(back/front). Can i set more than one sess_cookie_name?

Comment: If you have independent CodeIgniter installs for front and back, then you could use different sess_cookie_name values for your installations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigneter session library to handle this. If the user logs in admin, you can create (and check) a variable in session like, i.e:

```
$this->session->userdata('is_admin',TRUE);
```

And store the data in a specific object in session only in backend. When logout only delete this session data, and then, the user still be logged in frontend.

Check: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The problem is with that auto generated session id, i suppose is browser limitation. I can't control the session id, and the browser uses that id whether you are logged in or just visit the page. It just assaigns it with the http header.

Comment: Yes, but that session id is autogenerated and it will be reassigned when logged out. I provably don't understand the problem but, if you want 2 different users logged in (frontend and backend) you should create 2 different loggins systems, with their checks (is_admin, is_user) or something like this.

Comment: I can login on the both at the same time,the problem is that both share the same session and if you destroy the session on one end, the other end is affected as well. Both use the same session id and different userdata assigned by me but the session id is assasign from codeigniter or the browser, i dont' know. I think it's browser limitataion, because i've tried to log in to facebook, the same way from one browser with different users at the same time, but it is not posible.

Comment: Ok, but, what you are trying to accomplish? It's no possible to have different users at same time, this is the meaning of session, it's limited to 1 user. I'm saying that if you need a user to be able to access to backend and frontend in the same time, and others users only in the frontend, you will need a database record for that and check if is user or admin.

Comment: I understand that. I'm login in the back with admin user id and in the front with costumer id, from the same browser, at the same time.No problem. The problem is when i logout from one end and destroy the session,  i'm logged out on the other end as well, because apparantly the sess_destroy() function uses that session id to identify the session. And since both ends uses the same session id, it destroyes the session on both ends.

Comment: Ok, if you use sess_destroy() you are deleting all the session. You should use your own function for loggout like:

`function logout_admin(){ $this->session->unset_userdata('is_admin_logged') }`

and then, in the __constructor() of the admin controller, check if the user has in the session:

`if(!$this->session->userdata('is_admin')){ redirect('login'); }`

And setting this session data when loggin correctly.

Comment: I've sorted out the login problem. The thing is that entire app uses same cookie name, and when you destroy the session it refers to that sess_cookie_name. I wonder if i can set 2 different sess_cookie_names for front and back end in the config file?